# On Click event not firing from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

In my code below , my `("OnClick")` is not firing. Does anyone know why?

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("OnClick") = "window.location.href='MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID='" _
   + GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID").ToString()



Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        Dim Index As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("OnClick") = "window.location.href='MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID='" + GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID").ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit above.

Comment: Can you correct your code and post it completely please ?

Comment: I don't understand you?

Comment: @Kallumasaurus post the full code here not just an attribute adding line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error in your attribute, as you are adding the value of the ID **after** the closing single quote...

For example, if the ID was `12`, you're sending this to the browser...

```
window.location.href='MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID='12
```

Note that the `12` is not part of the URL.

You should have the following instead...

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onclick") =
  string.Format("window.location.href='MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID={0}';",
  GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID").ToString())
```

Also note, as of .NET 4.0 it is unnecessary to have the `_` character when spanning over multiple lines.

Comment: I will give this a go and get back to you on this.

Comment: Well done sir , hats off to you. this has fixed my issue with the upmost ease.

Comment: Great - glad to hear it was an easy fix. A 2nd pair of eyes is normally all that's needed  :-)

Comment: That's exactly it my friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 e.Row.Attributes("onClick") = "CallFunction('" & Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID")) & "');"
```

JS code:

```
function CallFunction(val)
{
   // do your login here
}
```

Comment: I don't need to add a function into this , makes things way to complicated.